# MySql Query - Select Where, Alias & parameter

Tags: c#, mysql, alias, where-clause

I'm having some trouble with a MySQL Select Where statement that uses aliases and parameters.  My problem lies with the Where part of the statement.  As it stands, I'm not returning any results when I try to use any parameters.

The statement in question is:

```
SELECT postcode, suburb, streetname, categorycode, DATE_FORMAT(dateRecorded, '%d/%m/%Y') AS Expr1, DATE_FORMAT(dateLastModified, '%d/%m/%Y') AS Expr2, status FROM incidentdetails WHERE (postcode = @postcode) AND (suburb = @suburb) AND (categorycode = @categorycode) AND (status = @status)
```

Executing this query with the correct parameters returns the right columns, but no data.

Removing the where clause entirely I get the full table as expected.

Altering the where clause from `WHERE (postcode = @postcode) AND (suburb = @suburb) AND (categorycode = @categorycode) AND (status = @status)` to `WHERE (postcode = 4020)`does work -- as expected.

Replacing the WHERE clause with (postcode = @postcode) and passing the parameter (as below) does not work .

`sqlFillRelated.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", int.Parse(PostcodeTxtBox.Text.ToString()))`

The full query (with parameters) works successfully when run from the server explorer SQL command.

```
        string sqlFILL = "SELECT postcode, suburb, streetname, categorycode, DATE_FORMAT(dateRecorded, '%d/%m/%Y') AS Expr1, DATE_FORMAT(dateLastModified, '%d/%m/%Y') AS Expr2, status FROM incidentdetails WHERE (postcode = @postcode) AND (suburb = @suburb) AND (categorycode = @categorycode) AND (status = @status)";
    string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM incidentdetails WHERE (postcode = @postcode) AND (suburb = @suburb) AND (categorycode = @categorycode) AND (status = @status)";
    MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(sqlconnection);
    mycon.Open();
    MySqlCommand selectRelatedCmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, mycon);
    MySqlCommand sqlFillRelated = new MySqlCommand(sqlFILL, mycon);
    int matches = 0;
    selectRelatedCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", int.Parse(PostcodeTxtBox.Text.ToString()));
    selectRelatedCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@suburb", SuburbTxtBox.Text.ToString());
    selectRelatedCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categorycode",IncidentTypeDropList.Text.ToString());
    selectRelatedCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "Open");
    sqlFillRelated.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", int.Parse(PostcodeTxtBox.Text.ToString()));
    sqlFillRelated.Parameters.AddWithValue("@suburb", SuburbTxtBox.Text.ToString());
    sqlFillRelated.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categorycode", IncidentTypeDropList.Text.ToString());
    sqlFillRelated.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "Open");

    matches = int.Parse(selectRelatedCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    if (matches == 0)
    {
        matchingIncidentPanel.Visible = false;  
    }
    else if (matches >= 1)
    {
        matchingIncidentPanel.Visible = true;
    }

    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlFILL, mycon);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    da.Fill(table);
    g.DataSource = table;
    g.DataBind();

    mycon.Close();
```

Comment: I think you should also add tag for the language you are accessing MySQL from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is a long shot because I am not sure what language are you using (is it C#?) but it strikes me odd that you use @ when setting the parameters.

Typically, you use some magic character to denote parameter in SQL query, but when you are setting it programatically you omit this character.

Did you try

```
sqlFillRelated.Parameters.AddWithValue("status", "Open")
```

instead of

```
sqlFillRelated.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "Open")
```

?

Comment: I'm using C#, developing an ASP application with MySql as database.  The @ denotes a parameter for Mysql queries, and the AddWithValue method overloads as (string ParameterName, object value), and as far as I'm aware the parameter name needs to have the @ (it's working in my other queries -- and I believe mysql does support named queries?).

Answer (score 1):

It is C#.  Ditch the '@' prefixes to the params in the C# code.

Comment: Ah.  It really does work, thanks to both of you!  Where did I pick up that @ naming convention from...?

Comment: From MySQL script conventions, multiple SQL stored procedure conventions, everything. *Don't feel bad!* It's a pain the @ char breaks things, it took, me 2 days to figure it out years ago when I did the *same thing* and you're like the 10th other person I've seen post on this same issue.